# Hierarchical Paragraph numbering with leading text

Tags: sectioning

I'm new to Tex and LaTeX and I don't know where to even look for an answer.
I would like to use LaTeX to produce a document (requirements document) where the requirements paragraphs/subparagraphs are numbered with leading text followed by a hierarchical number.

For example

```
FAU_GEN.1 Audit data generation

Hierarchical to: No other components.

FAU_GEN.1.1 The TSF shall be able to generate an audit record of the following auditable
events:
    a) Start-up and shutdown of the audit functions; 
    b) All auditable events for the [selection: minimum, basic, detailed, not
       specified] level of audit; and
    c) [assignment: other specifically defined auditable events].

FAU_GEN.1.2 The TSF shall record within each audit record at least the following
information: 
    a) Date and time of the event, type of event, subject identity, and the
       outcome (success or failure) of the event; and
    b) For each audit event type, based on the auditable event definitions of
       the functional components included in the PP/ST, [assignment: other
       audit relevant information] 

Dependencies: FPT_STM.1 Reliable time stamps
```

The dependency is a xref to another requirement and is numbered as that xref requirement.  The FPT_STM.1 does not auto increment here.

This FAU_GEN.1 requirement may be followed by another requirement that WOULD auto increment as:

FAU_GEN.2 User identity association
    Hierarchical to: No other components.

FAU_GEN.2.1 The TSF shall be able to associate each auditable event with the identity of the
            user that caused the event.

Dependencies: FAU_GEN.1 Audit data generation
              FIA_UID.1 Timing of identification

The closest example I can find on the web is https://www.niap-ccevs.org/Documents_and_Guidance/cc_docs/cc_v21_part2.pdf

section 3.2 on page 19.  Though this sample document has a lot of other fluff.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide at least a little bit of code showing, what documentclass you want to use. It is difficult to understand your question: What do you mean by requirements? Maybe you just write an example using words like chapter, section, paragraph. Have you searched the site for [custom couters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+counter)?

Comment: I'm also not very clear what you are trying to do. ABC is one category of XYZ and EFG is another, but you would like all requirements in the chapter on XYZ to have a number which is prefixed with ABC_EFG? Won't that be confusing? Will there always be 2 categories and you always want the prefix to be CAT1_CAT2? Or will this vary? Do you have a link you could post to an example of this kind of document?

Comment: Sorry - I fixed up the sample, but that didn't post.  I am trying to (re)produce a requirements document.  Requirements are numbered hierarchically with a leading bit of text as
ABC_DEF.1, ABC_DEF.2 ABC_DEF.2.1   where the ABC_DEF is the section heading.  The section heading is usually followed by some text.  Then the requirements follow.  I have a template in Word - but really don't like word..

Comment: Your requirements are still totally unclear, why does the numbering change from ABC_DEF.2 to ABC_DEF.2.1 with the same heading?, please make an example document that people could use to test and show (as a comment on each heading perhaps) exactly what text and what number you want. paste it inline into your question then use the `{}` button to indent it by 4 spaces which will mark it as a code block.

Comment: so... dependencies there is numbered 1 do they start from 1 just at the start of the document or start at 1 every paragraph or every subparagraph (I'm assuming subparagraph numbering is reset every paragraph)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{artikel3}
\catcode`\_=11 % use \sb if you need a math subscript
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\reqpara[1]{%
\def\thispara{#1}\paragraph{}}

\newcommand\reqsubpara{\subparagraph{}}

\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}

\newenvironment{deps}{%
\par
\textbf{Dependencies}
\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi)}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\thispara.\@nameuse{the#1}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\ParaFont{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\SParaFont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\reqpara{FAU_GEN}
Audit data generation

Hierarchical to: No other components.

\reqsubpara
The TSF shall be able to generate an audit record of the following auditable
events
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Start-up and shutdown of the audit functions; 
    \item All auditable events for the [selection: minimum, basic, detailed, not
       specified] level of audit; and
    \item {}[assignment: other specifically defined auditable events].
\end{enumerate}

\reqsubpara
The TSF shall record within each audit record at least the following
information: 
    a) Date and time of the event, type of event, subject identity, and the
       outcome (success or failure) of the event; and
    b) For each audit event type, based on the auditable event definitions of
       the functional components included in the PP/ST, [assignment: other
       audit relevant information] 

\begin{deps}
\item[FPT_SMT.1] Reliable time stamps
\end{deps}

\end{document}
```